# Sending more than one model (table) to the same view Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, controller, routes, laravel-blade

I have tried to find answers but struggle with that. I am practising usage of MVC. I was able to return one whole table from database in to the view and display it contents. What I am struggling with is to do the same with second table from the same database. Is there any way to return two separate tables into same view? What if I want to display data from three or more separate tables in to the same page (view). How one can do that? I would appreciate any help and explanation. If my explanation is not clear please let me know.

Controller DBController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\example;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DBController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show a list of all of the application's users.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function hakunamatata()
    {
        $tests = DB::table('somename')->get();                              

        return view('pages.testcursorfollow', ['tests' => $tests]);
    }
    public function testowanie()
    {
        $checks = DB::table('somename2')->get();

        return view('pages.testcursorfollow', ['checks' => $checks]);
    } 
}
```

My Routes in web.php: (I know that 'kursor' part should not be the same for both, but that is the idea, to return both of them to the same view; or three, or more if needed)

```
Route::get('kursor', 'example\DBController@hakunamatata');
Route::get('kursor', 'example\DBController@testowanie');
```

My view testcursorfollow.php:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>col1</th>
    <th>col2</th>
    <th>col3</th>
    <th>col4</th>
    <th>col5</th>
  </tr>
  @if (isset($tests))
  @foreach ($tests as $user)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->col1}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->col2}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->col3}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->col4}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->col5}}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
@endif


</table>

<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
  </tr>

 @foreach ($checks as $check)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$check->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$check->Name}}</td>
    <td>{{$check->Surname}}</td>
  </tr>

@endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with compact.

For example:

```PHP
function getStuff() {
  $posts = DB::table('posts')->get();
  $comments = DB::table('comments')->get();

  return view('pages.testcursorfollow', compact('posts', 'comments'));
}
```

Comment: Right, I will try it immediately. Thank you Nieck.

Comment: Excellent, it worked! Great stuff. I need to read a bit about 'compact'.

Comment: @RafalM Nice! it is actually quite easy. Everything you put between the brackets will be given to the view that you are returning.